# Why Zxing barcode result always error

Tags: android, barcode, zxing

I am a beginner Android developer. For almost 4 days I've tried to make ZXing barcode with my own application, but the result is always zero. I finally found a tutorial that explains to connect to ZXing via intent. It compiles just fine, but the application always results in an error after scanning a barcode.

Here is my code:

```
// java file --------------

package zxing.src;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;


public class zxing_act extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        private EditText edittext1, editText2;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        EditText edittext1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext1);
        EditText editText2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);

        Button next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
            intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE");
            startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
        }

       });


    }

   public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
       if (requestCode == 0) {
          if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            String contents = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
            edittext1.setText(contents);
            String format = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT");
            editText2.setText(format);             
        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            // Handle cancel
        }
      }
   }
}

// manifest file --------
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="zxing.src"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
    <application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".zxing_act" >
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.ROBOTICEYEOMG"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>

// layout file ----------
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <EditText
       android:id="@+id/edittext1"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <EditText
       android:id="@+id/editText2"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


   <Button
      android:id="@+id/button1"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="Button" />

</LinearLayout>
```

---

I'd like to know where my mistake is. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: It would be helpful, if you post messages from logcat.

Comment: that's it, post logcat please

Comment: Please don't copy our project name and package in your code.

Comment: Hi all, my question finnaly answered. thnks 4 all. @ sean and integrator team : I really appreciate all your efforts, I simply add your project in build path to the application but I did not change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't specified what your error is, but, I can suggest that use the provided `IntentIntegrator` class in `android-integration` in the project rather than try to write your own integration code.

Comment: Hi sean, thats it wonderfull code from IntentIntegrator. I have success to running my code without error and get the result. thanks for your goodness to write that code. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your manifest file from

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.ROBOTICEYEOMG"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
</intent-filter>
```

to

```
  <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
```

Comment: thanks for the advice but the result remains the same. btw i use this procedure with barcode scanner app installed.

Comment: No, he doesn't want to listen for the intent. He needs to send the intent.